# Chart.plugins.register beforeDraw does not work when using ChartsJS 3.x

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I updated the Chart JS version to 3.5 and since then I got Chart.pluginService.register error. I saw that I had to change it to Chart.register, but it still gives me errors when I run my app.

This is my code:

```js
Chart.register({

  beforeDraw: function(chart, args, options) {

    if (chart.chart.chart.config.type == 'doughnut') {

      const width = chart.chart.width;
      const height = chart.chart.height;
      const ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

      var text;

      ctx.restore();
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 3000, 3000);

      fontSize = (height / sizeLabel1).toFixed(2); //250
      ctx.fillStyle = colorLabel1; //"#FFFEFE"
      ctx.font = '400 ' + fontSize * 13 + 'px "Titillium Web"';
      text = chart.config.options.elements.center.text1; //"CICLE " + currentCicle + "/" + totalCicles; 
      textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
      textY = (height / positionLabel1); //3.30                          
      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);

      fontSize = (height / sizeLabel2).toFixed(2); //90
      ctx.fillStyle = colorLabel2; //"#FFFEFE"
      ctx.font = 'Bold ' + fontSize * 13 + 'px "Titillium Web"';
      text = chart.config.options.elements.center.text2; //"1"+"' "+"30"+"''"; 
      textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
      textY = (height / positionLabel2); //2.70                                          
      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);

      fontSize = (height / sizeLabel3).toFixed(2); //150       
      ctx.fillStyle = colorLabel3; //"#FFFEFE"
      ctx.font = '100 ' + fontSize * 13 + 'px "Titillium Web"';
      text = chart.config.options.elements.center.text3;
      textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
      textY = (height / positionLabel3); //1.90                 
      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);

      fontSize = (height / sizeLabel4).toFixed(2); //200                   
      ctx.fillStyle = colorLabel4; //"#FFFEFE"
      ctx.font = '400 ' + fontSize * 13 + 'px "Titillium Web"';
      text = chart.config.options.elements.center.text4;
      textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
      textY = (height / positionLabel4); //1.50              
      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);

      ctx.save();
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Error: class does not have id: function (chart,args,options) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Plugins need an ID to function as stated in the error message so chart.js knows where to get the options from for example so your plugin should look like this:

```js
Chart.register({
  id: 'customPluginName',
  beforeDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    // Actual plugin code
  }
})
```

Comment: Now I have new errors which says: Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '2' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.

Comment: I destroy the graph if it exists before I used it, and all the variables of Chart are globals

Answer (score -1):

In 2022 we have [ChartJS version 4.0.1](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.0.1/)

The way we add plugins is this way. Also, they can have a particular configuration using `plugins`: { 'customLabels': {} }` we can add some parameters and process them in the hook.

```js
const datasets = [{
  label: 'Dataset 1',
  data: [
    50.09173525,
    9.40843621,
    25.41237997,
    10.44924554,
    84.27211934
  ],
  backgroundColor: [
    'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
  ]
}]

const data = {
  labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'],
  datasets,
}


const plugin = {
  id: 'customLabels',
  defaults: {
    labels: []
  },
  beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
    if (chart.config.type !== 'doughnut') return

    const {width, height, ctx} = chart

    const labels = options.labels
    if (!labels) return
    
    ctx.save()
      
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 0, 0)
    
    const index = 1
    const total = labels.length
    for (const label of labels) {
        const text = label.text || `Circle: ${index}/${total}` 
        const size = label.size || 100
        const color = label.color || '#FFFEFE'
        const weight = label.weight || 400
        const pos = label.pos || 3.30

        ctx.fillStyle = color

        const fontSize = (height / size).toFixed(2)
        ctx.font = `${weight} ${fontSize * 13}px "Titillium Web"`

        
        const textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2)
        const textY = (height / pos) //3.30    
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY)
    }

    ctx.restore()
  }
}


const options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      'customLabels': {
        labels: [
          {
            size: 250,
          },
          {
            size: 90,
            weight: 700,
          },
          {
            size: 150,
            weight: 100,
            pos: 1.90,
          },
          {
            size: 200,
            pos: 1.50,
          },
        ]
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [plugin],
}


const $canvas = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = new Chart($canvas, options)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 98vw; height: 180px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.0.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-gQhCDsnnnUfaRzD8k1L5llCCV6O9HN09zClIzzeJ8OJ9MpGmIlCxm+pdCkqTwqJ4JcjbojFr79rl2F1mzcoLMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question since the question goes about globally registered plugins, not locally

Comment: Before version 3 if was the way to implemented after version 3 it is recommended to do this way. So this explanation is the correct way to implement it using version 3 and 4

Comment: The recomended way is not by registering it locally, the only reason when you register it locally is when you apply it to a single chart instance, with this way of registering it you have duplicate code

Comment: Why there is always toxic people like you, check the code, he is doing this just for the doughnut and hard coding many values, it is obviously for a single chart for that reason I'm providing the best way to implementing. Are you developer? if you know the definition of plugin is "expectational behavior", if his code were related with a corsair or general stuff I will show the optimal to do it. So stop your toxicity. This is an alternative to the global hardcode way he is doing and if you that is the best go and apply it don't come to bother other people with your negativity.